# Why is the text appearing as single row instead of 4 rows?

Tags: html, row, multiple-columns

I am new to programming and am trying to get these 4 lines of text to be 4 separate rows instead of 1 single row, could someone please explain what is wrong with my code? Thank you!

```html
<div class="row">
    <div clas="col">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class=col"
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    div clas="col">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class=col"
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in line 8 you have `div clas="col">` - should this be `<div class="col">`?

Comment: you should also post the css definition of the classes `row` and `col`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the Flex property in CSS

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .row{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class=col">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div clas="col">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class=col">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```